# Beautiful Soup - download css items

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I want to scrab a web page, so I try to download all: images, `.js` elements and also `.css` elemnts. To download .cc script I wrote a function:

```
for item in self.soup.findAll('link', {'type':'text/css','href':True}):
 print item['href']
 # do some things
```

And it usually works quite well but I found some pages, for which it doesn't work and I can not understand why. For example a page: `http://www.nasa.gov`. If I will open this page in my browser and save as a file, I can notice that inside a source I have:

```
<link media="all" href="NASA_files/widget120.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="NASA_files/sayt.css" type="text/css">
```

and few more. But when I run my code it doesn't print anything. The question is: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe those pages are just "wrongly" formatted...

Comment: @RikPoggi But how I can recognize if the page is wrongly formatted?

Comment: The quickest way would be to run it against your script and if it fails (doesn't return anything) it means that you'll have to find another way. (It's not pretty, I know)

Comment: @RikPoggi But truly saying looking on source code of nasa.gov it seems that everything is ok

Comment: Have you tried basic debugging like `print(self.soup.prettify())` to make sure you have the object you think you do?

Answer (score 2):

If you run your code on just the HTML you posted, it works.

It's not working if you fetch nasa.gov in your script because the actual source of that page does not include those elements. There are a bunch of inline `<style>` elements with `@include`s in them. The `<link>` elements are probably added using Javascript after the page is loaded.

Comment: Can you see those links at `nasa.gov` through the browser developer tools?

Comment: Yes, and if you disable javascript they go away